# Error on the first code I wrote on C++. Don't know what's happening

Tags: visual-c++

I wrote this code for my class and when i debug it runs but shuts down within seconds i dont know what i'm doing wrong here. I am really new to C++ so.

here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
 {
  double gallons;
  double startmile;
  double endmile;
  double totalmilestravelled;

  cout << "This Program Calculates your vehicle's gas mileage on this trip\n" << endl;
  cout << "What is the number of gallons consumed on the trip: ";
  cin  >> gallons;
  cout << "\nWhat was your ending mile?";
  cin  >> endmile;
  cout << "\nWhat was your starting mile?";
  cin  >> startmile;

  totalmilestravelled = endmile-startmile;
  double mpg = totalmilestravelled/gallons;

  cout << "your gas mileage is: " << mpg << endl;
  return 0;
  }
```

and this is the error: 
The program '[9848] gasmileage.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an error. The program exited normally. When you run a program, it executes and exits with an exit code specified by the program. In this case you return 0, so the program exits with code 0. If you want the program to "pause" to allow you to see the result of the program before it closes, add this just before the return statement:

`cin.ignore(128, '\n');`

`cin.get();`

The first line discards newlines that were left over in the standard input. Don't worry about this too much until you learn more about the input stream, but you need to do this if you are attempting to read a string after reading numeric input from the user. The second line will prompt the user for some input (push return). You don't care what the input is, and you aren't going to do anything with the input. You just want to force the program to wait for user input so that you can see what's going on before continuing with the program (which in this case the program immediately exit).

Think about programs that say "Press any key." It's the same thing we're doing here. Giving the user a moment to view the output.